# Simple linear regression for data set

Tags: c#, .net, statistics, linear-algebra, linear-regression

I am looking to create a trend function in C# for a set of data and it seems like using a big math library is a bit overkill for my needs.

Given a list of values such as 6,13,7,9,12,4,2,2,1. I would like to get the slope of the simple linear regression (to see if it is decreasing or increasing) and the next estimated value. I know that there are massive libraries out there that can do that and more, but I wanted a more simple approach.

I'm not big into statistics, so if someone could lead me in a way to do this, it would be appreciated.

Comment: googling for `c# linear regression` revealed quite a few hits that seem to address your need with a simple function.  What's insufficient about them?

Comment: Most dealt with matrices of 2D elements when I am only concerned with a 1 dimensional set of data.

Comment: It's not really one-dimensional.  You just are implying an equal spacing between elements. So you seem to really have [0,6], [1,13], [2,7], [3,9], etc.  Ultimately you seem to need to know both the slope and intercept, so you can calculate the next estimated value. On the surface, this one seems useful: https://gist.github.com/tansey/1375526

Answer (score 8):

You don't need massive libraries.  The formulas are relatively simple.

Given a pair of arrays for your x and y data, you'll calculate the least square fit coefficients like [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html)

Formulas (27) and (28) are the two you want.  The coding involves little more than sums and sums of squares of the input array values.

Here is a Java class and its JUnit test class for those who want more detail:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Simple linear regression example using Wolfram Alpha formulas.
 * User: mduffy
 * Date: 10/22/2018
 * Time: 10:56 AM
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623129/simple-linear-regression-for-data-set/15623183?noredirect=1#comment92773017_15623183
 */
public class SimpleLinearRegressionExample {

    public static double slope(double [] x, double [] y) {
        double slope = 0.0;
        if ((x != null) && (y != null) && (x.length == y.length) && (x.length > 0)) {
            slope = correlation(x, y)/sumOfSquares(x);
        }
        return slope;
    }

    public static double intercept(double [] x, double [] y) {
        double intercept = 0.0;
        if ((x != null) && (y != null) && (x.length == y.length) && (x.length > 0)) {
            double xave = average(x);
            double yave = average(y);
            intercept = yave-slope(x, y)*xave;
        }
        return intercept;
    }

    public static double average(double [] values) {
        double average = 0.0;
        if ((values != null) && (values.length > 0)) {
            average = Arrays.stream(values).average().orElse(0.0);
        }
        return average;
    }

    public static double sumOfSquares(double [] values) {
        double sumOfSquares = 0.0;
        if ((values != null) && (values.length > 0)) {
            sumOfSquares = Arrays.stream(values).map(v -> v*v).sum();
            double average = average(values);
            sumOfSquares -= average*average*values.length;
        }
        return sumOfSquares;
    }

    public static double correlation(double [] x, double [] y) {
        double correlation = 0.0;
        if ((x != null) && (y != null) && (x.length == y.length) && (x.length > 0)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
                correlation += x[i]*y[i];
            }
            double xave = average(x);
            double yave = average(y);
            correlation -= xave*yave*x.length;
        }
        return correlation;
    }
}
```

JUnit test class:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * JUnit tests for simple linear regression example.
 * User: mduffy
 * Date: 10/22/2018
 * Time: 11:53 AM
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623129/simple-linear-regression-for-data-set/15623183?noredirect=1#comment92773017_15623183
 */
public class SimpleLinearRegressionExampleTest {

    public static double tolerance = 1.0e-6;

    @Test
    public void testAverage_NullArray() {
        // setup
        double [] x = null;
        double expected = 0.0;
        // exercise
        double actual = SimpleLinearRegressionExample.average(x);
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual, tolerance);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAverage_EmptyArray() {
        // setup
        double [] x = {};
        double expected = 0.0;
        // exercise
        double actual = SimpleLinearRegressionExample.average(x);
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual, tolerance);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAverage_Success() {
        // setup
        double [] x = { 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 7.0, 9.0 };
        double expected = 4.0;
        // exercise
        double actual = SimpleLinearRegressionExample.average(x);
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual, tolerance);
    }


    @Test
    public void testSumOfSquares_NullArray() {
        // setup
        double [] x = null;
        double expected = 0.0;
        // exercise
        double actual = SimpleLinearRegressionExample.sumOfSquares(x);
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual, tolerance);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSumOfSquares_EmptyArray() {
        // setup
        double [] x = {};
        double expected = 0.0;
        // exercise
        double actual = SimpleLinearRegressionExample.sumOfSquares(x);
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual, tolerance);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSumOfSquares_Success() {
        // setup
        double [] x = { 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 7.0, 9.0 };
        double expected = 52.0;
        // exercise
        double actual = SimpleLinearRegressionExample.sumOfSquares(x);
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual, tolerance);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCorrelation_NullX_NullY() {
        // setup
        double [] x = null;
        double [] y = null;
        double expected = 0.0;
        // exercise
        double actual = SimpleLinearRegressionExample.correlation(x, y);
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual, tolerance);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCorrelation_DifferentLengths() {
        // setup
        double [] x = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0 };
        double [] y = { 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.15, 0.18, 0.20 };
        double expected = 0.0;
        // exercise
        double actual = SimpleLinearRegressionExample.correlation(x, y);
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual, tolerance);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCorrelation_Success() {
        // setup
        double [] x = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0 };
        double [] y = { 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.15, 0.18 };
        double expected = 0.308;
        // exercise
        double actual = SimpleLinearRegressionExample.correlation(x, y);
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual, tolerance);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSlope() {
        // setup
        double [] x = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
        double [] y = { 6.0, 5.0, 7.0, 10.0 };
        double expected = 1.4;
        // exercise
        double actual = SimpleLinearRegressionExample.slope(x, y);
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual, tolerance);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIntercept() {
        // setup
        double [] x = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
        double [] y = { 6.0, 5.0, 7.0, 10.0 };
        double expected = 3.5;
        // exercise
        double actual = SimpleLinearRegressionExample.intercept(x, y);
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual, tolerance);
    }
}
```

Comment: That "relatively simple" formula makes me poop a little

Comment: You shouldn't be scared.  It's little more than adding sums of lists of numbers.

Comment: That's because the syntax used is not immediately intuitive to readers who aren't familiar with it. This is a great case where a simple example would dramatically simplify understanding.

Comment: I guess it wasn’t clear to me what spoon size was needed to feed this when I wrote it five years ago.

Comment: @duffymo Byte-size spoons are always helpful. ;)

Comment: "Bite" size is exactly what I gave five years ago.  Don't be scared by the summation signs at Wolfram.

Comment: Please see if the code I've added fits the bill.  It's not C#, but Java should be easy to port.

Answer (score 8):

My own code for future prediction(Example for 15th day from first day)

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] xVal = new double[9]
        {

    ...


           };
        double[] yVal = new double[9]  {
     ...

        };
        double rsquared;
        double yintercept;
        double slope;
        LinearRegression(xVal, yVal,0,9, out rsquared, out yintercept, out slope);
        Console.WriteLine( yintercept + (slope*15));//15 is xvalue of future(no of day from 1)

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static void LinearRegression(double[] xVals, double[] yVals,
                                        int inclusiveStart, int exclusiveEnd,
                                        out double rsquared, out double yintercept,
                                        out double slope)
    {
        Debug.Assert(xVals.Length == yVals.Length);
        double sumOfX = 0;
        double sumOfY = 0;
        double sumOfXSq = 0;
        double sumOfYSq = 0;
        double ssX = 0;
        double ssY = 0;
        double sumCodeviates = 0;
        double sCo = 0;
        double count = exclusiveEnd - inclusiveStart;

        for (int ctr = inclusiveStart; ctr < exclusiveEnd; ctr++)
        {
            double x = xVals[ctr];
            double y = yVals[ctr];
            sumCodeviates += x * y;
            sumOfX += x;
            sumOfY += y;
            sumOfXSq += x * x;
            sumOfYSq += y * y;
        }
        ssX = sumOfXSq - ((sumOfX * sumOfX) / count);
        ssY = sumOfYSq - ((sumOfY * sumOfY) / count);
        double RNumerator = (count * sumCodeviates) - (sumOfX * sumOfY);
        double RDenom = (count * sumOfXSq - (sumOfX * sumOfX))
         * (count * sumOfYSq - (sumOfY * sumOfY));
        sCo = sumCodeviates - ((sumOfX * sumOfY) / count);

        double meanX = sumOfX / count;
        double meanY = sumOfY / count;
        double dblR = RNumerator / Math.Sqrt(RDenom);
        rsquared = dblR * dblR;
        yintercept = meanY - ((sCo / ssX) * meanX);
        slope = sCo / ssX;
    }
```

Comment: It works nice when I feed X array with 0,1,2,3...and Y array consist of linearly progressing values as well.  I understand that values from array X as distance between values from Y array, so they should increase linearly as well as per Chris Farmer comment.

When I feed Y array with something like: 1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1 it cannot predict correctly anymore

Comment: Is it because this method expects "roughly "linear progress within Y array?

Comment: Whey you draw XY pane, the X&Y both are having linear progress,

Comment: By the way @Aristo,
is it matching the output values if you are place it in excel and apply linear regression

Comment: I noticed ssY = sumOfYSq - ((sumOfY * sumOfY) / count); is not used?

Comment: If anyone wants to calculate the sample standard deviation (sigma) with this, just put this at the bottom and also add it as another out parameter: stdDev = Math.Sqrt(ssY / (count - 1));